# Print kernel memory layout

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-memory, profiling

Userland memory layout can be inspected by looking into `/proc/self/maps`.

[image]

I am wondering if there is a similar facility allowing to inspect runtime kernel memory layout?

Comment: From inside the kernel, you mean? Or are you asking how to use a debugger with the kernel? Note that programming is off-topic here. You can ask programming questions on [so], but you'll need to be clearer.

Comment: Have you looked at the `dmesg` output shortly after a boot? It should show you some details.